# IE does, but Chrome/Firefox do not render SVG embedded image in "img" element

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, webkit

I'm trying to reference an SVG file using the "img" tag:

```
<img width="200" height="100"
     src="test.svg" 
     onerror="this.onerror = null; alert('error');"
     />
```

Generally this works, but if "test.svg" has an embedded .jpg image, then the image does not render.  This is true in Chrome and Firefox -- IE does render the image correctly.  Strangely, if I load "test.svg" directly in the browser, then the embedded image renders correctly on each of the browsers.

Here's an example of "test.svg" that shows what I mean:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="200" height="100">

    <!-- Text and shapes always render correctly -->
    <text x="20" y="20" font-size="20">some text</text>
    <ellipse ry="30" rx="30" 
             cy="50" cx="50" 
             stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" 
             fill="#FF0000" 
             />

    <!-- Embedded images render in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox -->
    <image xlink:href="test.jpg"
           width="100" height="100"
           x="100" />
</svg>
```

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer.  Is this a bug in Webkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any SVG image embedded via the `<img>` tag must be self-contained.  Any external references it has, such as to images, fonts or CSS files, will not be loaded.

The reasons for this are explained here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747

FF and webkit have made this change.  I guess IE hasn't yet.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Do you happen to have a reference for that? I did glance at the SVG spec, but didn't find anything to that effect.

Comment: If you need to, you can embed images and other resources as data URLs.

Comment: Funny -- I was thinking, it's a miracle, for once IE is actually a better browser; but nope, it's just another security hole.

Answer (score 0):

> You could possibly use an `<object>` tag with optional fallback to better handle svgs. Here's something you can do -

```
<object width="200" height="100" data='test.svg' onerror="this.onerror = null; alert('error');">
    <!-- fallback -->
    <img width="200" height="100" src="test.svg" onerror="this.onerror = null; alert('error');" />
</object>
```

***Where,*** your object tag will be loaded on first priority & if it fails for some reason, then your fallback will be loaded. In this case, I've written your original `img` as a fallback.